# Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught NoReadAccessException

Tags: android, kotlin

I just installed plugin and started converting it and it throws an exception

> Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught NoReadAccessException. Disable Plugin NoReadAccessException
>
> Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
>                   Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1,4,main] 355602237
>                   ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
>                   SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 2.3#AI-162.4069837 Studio, eap:false, os:Windows 7 6.1, java-version:JetBrains s.r.o 1.8.0_112-release-b06,6,main] 1229449779

Comment: Restart your android studio

Comment: i did but still watching it

Comment: Please use the built-in exception reporting system to report the exception to JetBrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have the correct version of the **Kotlin plugin** installed in Android Studio.

For Android studio 2.3.3 the correct version of Kotlin Plugin is **Kotlin 1.1.4-release-Studio2.3-1**

After downloading correct Kotlin plugin you should configure project like this.

Configure your **Project Gradle** like this.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And Your **Module Gradle** should be like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android

android {
....
....
}

dependencies{
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Update it and clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: The exception reported in the question is completely unrelated to the contents of build.gradle in the project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Android Studio v3.0.1 and kotlin plugin v1.2.0-release-Studio3.0-1

I solved it by uninstalling the kotlin plugin then installing it again.
Open Preferences, plugins, search kotlin, uninstall, then install again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by the following steps.

**Step1:** Disable Kotlin

**Step2:** Update Android Studio

**Step3:** Go to settings -> Kotlin Compiler -> and choose the following option

1. Language Version -> 1.3 (Experimental)  from the drop down
2. API Version -> 1.3 (Experimental)

Hope it will solve the problem